# Need help resolving a BindingExpression issue

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, binding-expressions

I have this style:

```
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button
                        Width="44"
                        Height="24"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                        Command="{Binding UninspectedPrintSelectedCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}">
```

But the command does not work correctly.  Looking at the output window yields this issue:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'UninspectedPrintSelectedCommand' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=701007577)'. BindingExpression:Path=UninspectedPrintSelectedCommand; DataItem='String' (HashCode=701007577); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

ViewModel ICommand Property:

```
    public ICommand UninspectedPrintSelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand<object>((print) =>
            {
                string printName = print.ToString();
                int indexOfX = printName.IndexOf('x');
                Row = DiePrint.GetRow(printName);
                Col = DiePrint.GetCol(printName);

                if (diePrint == null) { diePrint = new DiePrint(Row + "x" + Col); }
                else
                {
                    diePrint.Row = Convert.ToInt32(row);
                    diePrint.Col = Convert.ToInt32(col);
                }
                LoadMap();
            });
        }
    }
```

I have no idea how to resolve this.  How is the Command property of the Button being interpreted as a String?

If it means anything, this is in my App.xaml file, not the main window.

Comment: Code for the property?

Comment: You are binding to the `DataContext` of the `Button`, which is going to be set to the object used to instantiate the the view associated with the `DataTemplate`. Based on the output, the DataTemplate must be being used for a string.

Comment: @MatthewFrontino I added the view model's ICommand property that I am trying to bind to in the question

Comment: I don't think the issue is in the command or the data template itself (although sending the content of a button to a command seems a little odd.). I think it is most likely in how the data template is being used.

Comment: @Xavier, Yes I am binding the ListBox to an ObservableCollection<string>.  How can I set up this DataTemplate to use a Button with Command that passes in the Content of the Button to the ICommand property in the view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to have your binding use a source higher up in your visual tree, where the `DataContext` is set to the viewmodel you want, rather than being set to a string.

For example, assuming there is a `Grid` higher up with the right data context, you would use a binding like this:

```
{Binding DataContext.UninspectedPrintSelectedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}
```

Replace `Grid` with something that will reliably be in the visual tree at the right level.

Comment: I swapped my Command binding to this and replaced Grid with ListBox (since this Button is the ItemTemplates DataTemplate property of a ListBox) and get this output message:

Comment: BindingExpression path error: 'DiePrintNav' property not found on 'object' ''ListBox' (Name='lbxUninspectedPrints')'. BindingExpression:Path=DiePrintNav.UninspectedPrintSelectedCommand; DataItem='ListBox' (Name='lbxUninspectedPrints'); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: Sorry, I got the path of the binding slightly wrong, it needs to have `DataContext` in front of the command name. Updated my example.

Comment: Works great now!  Thanks.  Now I can't seem to get the Content of the Buttons ContentPresenter to be properly passed as a parameter :/

Comment: scratch that last comment, I got it.  Just had to use: